# How would you translate javascript reduce() to Swift 2?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, swift2, reduce

…provided js reduce() taking a 3-parameter function as follows?

```
var relevance = _(s.words).reduce( function (memo, freq, w) {
    var local = Math.log( 1 + freq );
    var global = Math.log( N / containing(w).length );
    return memo = memo + (local * global);
}, 0);
```

So far, I came up to:

```
let relevance = s.words.reduce(0) {
   (memo, freq, w) in

   var local = log( 1 + freq )
   var global = log( N / containing(w).length )

   return memo = memo + (local * global)
} // ~reduce()
```

But, reduce() doesn't compile due to the number of arg mismatch.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't know _Swift2_, but is `foo.bar(baz) {fizz in return buzz}` correct syntax? It looks very strange to me.

Comment: Paul S.: Yes it is. When the last parameter is a nullable closure, you can drop parenthesis and write the block after the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the reduce function as following:

```
[1, 3, 5].reduce(0) { previousValue, arrayValue in
    return previousValue + arrayValue
}

// returns 9
```

In your case you can get the index of the value by calling enumerate:

```
// indexValue is of type (index: Int, element: Int)
[1, 3, 5].enumerate().reduce(0) { previousValue, indexValue in
    // access index
    indexValue.index
    // access value
    indexValue.element
    return previousValue + indexValue.element
}

// returns also 9
```

Your code:

```
let relevance = s.words.enumerate().reduce(0) {
   (memo, freqW) in

   let freq = Double(freqW.index)
   let w = freqW.element

   // use let if you don't modify the value
   let local = log( 1 + freq )
   // you probably need to convert some of the variables to Double
   let global = log( N / containing(w).length )

   // in the next iteration memo will be this returned value
   return memo + (local * global)
}
```